# How to use Copy to slave plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm working on a job(say **Job A**) that has a file as a parameter. However, it triggers another job(say **Job B**) which restricts its execution on a remote machine(slave04) with a custom workspace `/home/jobB/workspace`.

Now I tried using ticking **Copy files into the job's workspace before building** in the Build Environment of **Job B** and selected custom relative path which is **"/"** in the option **Paths are relative to**.

There is the console output of copying process when I print the contents of present working directory (`ls -al`) of **job B** which is `/home/jobB/workspace` the file which is supposed to be copied is not there. Console output is here.

`[copy-to-slave] Copying 'var/work/jenkins_workspace/jobA/package.zip', excluding nothing, from 'file:/' on the master to 'file:/home/jobB/workspace/' on 'slave04'.`

Was my step correct? What should be the correct input in the field **Files to copy**? Are filenames(package.zip) and file path(var/work/package.zip) both valid? And what does **Paths are relative to** mean? In my case, I provided an additional option which is **"/"** in **Manage Jenkins->Configure Settings->Copy to slave**, so is it right that every path starting with /whateverpath is already relative to that option?

[Copy To Slave Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin)

Comment: What is the issue? Is the file not there at the end of the copy? Looks like everything worked, no? Then what is the question?

Comment: @Slav there is no file copied. But there was the process of copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have successfully copied uploaded file parameter from master job to slave job workspace.

**Procedure that didn't work:**

1. In *Manage Jenkins->Configure Settings->Copy to slave* I added a **Paths are relative to** option which is root of the master **(/)**
2. In slave job **Build Environment** configuration, I provided filepath such as `var/work/jenkins_workspace/jobA/package.zip` in the **Files to copy** and chose **Paths are relative to /**(root)
3. Result: File is not copied.

**Procedure that worked:**

1. In *Manage Jenkins->Configure Settings->Copy to slave* I added a **Paths are relative to** option which is **/var/work/jenkins_workspace/jobA**
2. In slave job **Build Environment** configuration, I provided filename such as `/package.zip` in the **Files to copy** and chose **Paths are relative to /var/work/jenkins_workspace/jobA**.
3. Result: File is copied.

So I guess, filepath is **not valid** in **Files to copy field**.